# how does spacemacs folding work?

Tags: folding, spacemacs

I'm looking at the code responsible for spacemacs code folding when origami is enabled. All I see is `hs-mode` enabled and keys bound to origami's folding functions.

When I put this in my emacs (not spacemacs) config, the folding doesn't work like it does in spacemacs. The following is what I found from `.emacs.d/layers/+spacemacs/spacemacs-editing/packages.el`.

```
(use-package origami
    :defer t
    :init
    (progn 
    (origami-global-mode 1)
    (define-key evil-normal-state-map "za" 'origami-forward-toggle-node)
    (define-key evil-normal-state-map "zc" 'origami-close-node)
    (define-key evil-normal-state-map "zC" 'origami-close-node-recursively)
    ...)
    ...)
```

When adding this to my emacs config:

1) folding doesn't work when a sexp is on line 1

2) folding works with defun but not use-package or other functions

I want to find the specific parser spacemacs uses to define folds so that I can replicate it in my own emacs. But I don't understand how the folding is working.

For example, it's confusing to me that when I check the binding of `za` for example with `describe-key`, I see the key is bound to `evil-toggle-fold` rather than `origami-toggle-fold` which is what I would expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `describe-key` shows that `za` is bound to `evil-toggle-fold`, I guess the layer is actually not enabled, and the folding behavior is just plain `hs-minor-mode`. You can try turn on `hs-minor-mode` and toggle the sexp with `C-c @ C-c`.

Comment: You're right the layer wasn't enabled. I'm still unsure though of how spacemacs actually gets the folding to work. Usually with evil, it will say "Folding is not supported in any of these major/minor modes" but in spacemacs folding just works. Do you have an idea of where I can look to find out why?

Comment: Evil folding just delegate to any of the folding mode available, the action is mapped in `evil-fold-list` variable. When it says "Folding not supported..." you just need to enable either `hs-minor-mode`, `outline-minor-mode` or `origami-mode` then it just work™.